# Функция id() в python возвращает только четные числа

Tags: python

Я решал задачку на Codewars про генерацию рандомного bool значения(True или False).
У одного из колабораторов было решение:

```
RandomBool=lambda:id(object())&1==0
```

Я подумал, что можно убрать сравнение с нулем:

```
RandomBool = lambda: id(object()) & 1
```

Но когда тестировал, то что я написал, оказалось, что id() возвращает только четные числа. Я подумал, что это мне так везет, что мне попадаются только четные числа, но зайдя в документацию на digitalOcean, я заметил, что и там в примерах возвращаются четные числа.
Было бы хорошо, если бы кто-то умный объяснил, почему так происходит, потому что я думал, эта функция просто возвращает случайное уникальное число.

Comment: id - адрес объекта, обычно кратен 4 или 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CPython **id** — это адрес объекта в памяти, а адреса кратны 8:

> Большинство современных компьютеров используют байтовую адресацию,
> причем каждый адрес идентифицирует один 8-разрядный байт памяти

[https://ru.bmstu.wiki/Адресация_памяти](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)